# Is my euler's method implementation correct?

Tags: java, numerical-methods

I'm writing code that should solve differential equation which is already given using euler's method. After getting results I plot them on graph. However I get incorrect values.

This is made to get transfer function feedback response. I've already tried to write euler's method otherwise (with same result). I checked few times if my differential equation is written correctly. I would like to know if problem lies here or somewhere else. I ran out of ideas what is wrong with this code.

```java
public static double inputSignal(double t, double A, double f, int typeOfSignal) {

        switch (typeOfSignal) {
            case 1:
                return A*cos(2*Math.PI*f*t);
            case 2:
                return A*(2/Math.PI)*asin(sin(2*Math.PI*f*t));
            case 3:
                return A*signum(sin(2*Math.PI*f*t));
            default:
                break;
        }

        return 0;
    }

public static double equation(double x, double xDerivative, double u, double uDerivative, double a0, double a1, double b0, double b1, double b2) {

        return (a1*uDerivative + a0*u - (a0+b0)*x - (a1+b1)*xDerivative)/b2; 
    }

 public static void eulerMethod(double h, double A, double f, double a0, double a1, double b0, double b1, double b2, int typeOfSignal) {

        double xn = 0, yn = 0, tn = 0, tn1; //x' = y; y' = f(x, y, u)
        double uDerivative;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            tn1 = tn + h;
            uDerivative= (inputSignal(tn1+h, A, f, typeOfSignal)-inputSignal(tn1, A, f, typeOfSignal))/h;
            xn = xn + h*equation(xn, yn, pobudzenie(tn1, A, f, typeOfSignal), uDerivative, a0, a1, b0, b1, b2);
            yn = yn + h*xn;
            System.out.println("Step" + i);
            System.out.println("Y(" + tn1 + ") " + " = " + yn);
            tn = tn1;
            results[i] = yn;
            inputGraph[i] = inputSignal(tn, A, f, typeOfSignal);
        }

    }
```

Differential equation is: `b2*x'' = a1*u' + a0*u - (a0+b0)*x - (a1+b1)*x'`

What I want to get for `euler2(0.0025, 1, 0.01, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1)` is
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r81Uv.jpg), but what I get from my code is [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SbTN.jpg)

As you can see my function has fluctuations that are not desired and it's amplitude is lower than expected (it's 0.2 while it should be 0.7).

Comment: Please translate the names in your code to english and format/indent the code

Comment: @Clashsoft Done, I hope it's clear now. Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The most likely error

You mixed up something in your first order system. You have

```
x'' = f(t,x,x',u,u')
```

and setting `y=x'` this should result in the first order system

```
x' = y
y' = f(t,x,y,u,u')
```

However, you interchanged the right sides in computing the updates of `x` and `y`, effectively changing the equation to `x''=f(t,x',x,u,u')` and displaying `x'`.

In your semi-explicit Euler implementation, the correct method implementation would be

```
yn = yn + h*equation(xn, yn, inputSignal(tn1, A, f, typeOfSignal), uDerivative, a0, a1, b0, b1, b2);
xn = xn + h*yn;
```

In a strict explicit Euler implementation, you would not use the newly computed `yn` in the `xn` update, but the old value. There needs to be some temporal cache variable involved.

---

### Improved first order system

You would get a more straightforward first-order system by setting

```
y=b2*x'+(a1+b1)*x-a1*u
```

so that then

```
x' = ( y - (a1+b1)*x+a1*u )/b2;
y' = a0*u-(a0+b0)*x
```

removing all the derivatives of `u` from the first-order system.

### Visual ODE solver test

If you produce a plot with different step sizes for either system, visual convergence is indicative of a correct implementation. Then any difference to the control plot means that probably there are differences in the ODE passed to your solver here and to your control solver.